# data not saving after strip charge (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strip

Hello I am having an issue with a test app. This app has a model called users who can accept points. These points are bought after the charge on the card. The problem I am having is that once the charge is done the points appear but once you change the page the points are gone. It is not saving on the database. Any help is great. Here is the charges.rb

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
  # Amount in cents
  @amount = 500

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'USD'
  )

  current_user.points = current_user.points + 500

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add:

```
current_user.save
```

after this line:

```
current_user.points = current_user.points + 500
```

Comment: god dang it... I forgot to save... You're awesome man thank you so much for the help  : )

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted for future user's reference.